# PowerShell regex to get just hex part in strings

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm working on a function that gets the map of string key and it's hex value.  I got the string key part working, but I'm having trouble getting the hex part to work.  This is my function so far:

```
function Get-Contents4_h{
  [cmdletbinding()]
  Param ([string]$fileContent) 

          #define Error_Failed_To_Do_A          0x81A0  /* random comments */
          #define Error_Failed_To_Do_B      0x810A

  # create an ordered hashtable to store the results
  $errorMap = [ordered]@{}
  # process the lines one-by-one
  switch -Regex ($fileContent -split '\r?\n') {
      'define ([\w]*)' { # Error_Failed_To_Do_  #this works fine
          $key = ($matches[1]).Trim()
      }
      '([0x\w]*)' {  # 0x04A etc #this does not work
          $errorMap[$key] = ($matches[1]).Trim()
      }
  }
  # output the completed data as object
  #[PsCustomObject]$errorMap
  return $errorMap
}
```

I'm going to be looping through the returned map and matching the hex value with the key in another object.

This is what the string parameter to the function looks like:

```
#define Error_Failed_To_Do_A            0x81A0  /* random comments */
#define Error_Failed_To_Do_B        0x810A
```

For some reason my

> 0x\w

regex is not returning anything in regex101.com. I've had luck with that with other hex numbers but not this time.

I've tried this and other variations as well: `^[\s\S]*?#[\w]*[\s\S]+([0x\w]*)`

This is with powershell 5.1 and VS Code.

Comment: Change `([0x\w]*)` to `(0x\w+)`

Comment: Nope, still not finding the hex part in regex101. When I let it all run through, the $errorMap is showing length 0, so maybe the key isn't working either....it worked in regex101 to find the key part.

Comment: Try my suggestion below (in PowerShell, not [on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Pc0855/1) ;-) ).

Comment: Mathias' answer should work for you. On a general note: to match a hex number literal prefixed with `0x` robustly, use `'\b0x[a-f0-9]+'` (assumes case-insensitive matching, as PowerShell does by default).

Comment: `'blah 0x810A blah' | select-string 0x\w+` highlights it correctly in powershell 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the `[...]` range construct around `0x\w` - the `0x` occurs exactly once in the input string, and the following characters appears *at least* once - but the expression `[0x\w]*` could be satisfied by an empty string (thanks to the `*`, 0-or-more quantifier).

I'd suggest matching the whole line at once with a single pattern instead:

```
switch -Regex ($fileContent -split '\r?\n') {
    '^\s*#define\s+(\w+)\s+(0x\w+)' {
        $key,$value = $Matches[1,2] |ForEach-Object Trim          
        $errorMap[$key] = $value
    }
}
```

Comment: Very cool.  Works very nicely.  Thank you!  I like how you refactored that to be more efficient too.

Comment: You're welcome! Slightly more efficient, but more importantly: _more accurate_ - now there's no chance you'll accidentally match a hex number on an unrelated line and overwrite the original/previous result :)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.  The square brackets match any one character inside them at a time.  The pattern with the square brackets has 18 matches in this line, the first match being empty string ''.  Regex101.com says the same thing (null).  https://regex101.com/r/PZ8Y8C/1  This would work `0x[\w]*`, but then you might as well drop the brackets.  I made an example data file and then a script on how I would do it.

```
'#define Error_Failed_To_Do_A 0x81A0  /* random comments */' | 
  select-string [0x\w]* -AllMatches | % matches | measure | % count

18
```

```
'#define Error_Failed_To_Do_A            0x81A0  /* random comments */
#define Error_Failed_To_Do_B        0x810A' | 
set-content file.txt
```

```
# Get-Contents4_h.ps1

Param ($file)

switch -Regex -File $file {
    'define (\w+).*(0x\w+)' {
      [pscustomobject]@{
        Error = $matches[1]
        Hex = $matches[2]
      }
    }
}
```

```
.\Get-Contents4_h file.txt

Error                Hex
-----                ---
Error_Failed_To_Do_A 0x81A0
Error_Failed_To_Do_B 0x810A
```